# How to subtract month correctly in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe has two columns. When I subtract them to get the month in between, I got some weird numbers. Here is an example:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'reg_date': [datetime(2017,3,1), datetime(2016,9,1)], 
                 'leave_date':[datetime(2017,7,1), datetime(2017,6,1)]})
test['diff_month'] = test.leave_date.dt.month - test.reg_date.dt.month
test
```

The output:

[image]

If a user's register_date is last year, I get a negative number (also incorrect as well).

What operations should I perform to get the correct time difference in month between two datetime column?

---

Update: I changed the example a bit so it reflects more about the issue I am facing. Don't down vote so fast guys.

A hack I did to fix this is:

```
test['real_diff'] = test.diff_month.apply(lambda x: x if x > 0 else 12+x)
```

I don't like the hack so I am curious if there is any other way of doing it.

Comment: b.month = 5, a.month = 12 --> 5 - 12 = -7 .. Maybe try `a.month` - `b.month`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Difference of 2 datetimes in months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015587/python-difference-of-2-datetimes-in-months)

Comment: Same example here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41199351/month-subtract-month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you can call `apply` and use `relativedelta` as @zipa suggested:

```
In[29]:
from dateutil import relativedelta
test['real_diff'] = test.apply(lambda row: relativedelta.relativedelta(row['leave_date'], row['reg_date']).months, axis=1)
test

Out[29]: 
  leave_date   reg_date  real_diff
0 2017-07-01 2017-03-01          4
1 2017-06-01 2016-09-01          9
```

Comment: Note this wont't work as expected if the difference is 12 months or more. For that you'll need to do use the `relativedelta.relativedelta.years` attribute as well.

Answer (score 2):

To get your result you can use `relativedelta` from `dateutil`:

```
import datetime
from dateutil import relativedelta

a = datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 1)
b = datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 1)

relativedelta.relativedelta(b, a).months
#5
```

Comment: Thanks zipa, the example I gave is not very accurate. I've updated my question.